# Custom node.js version on Openshift

Tags: node.js, shell, openshift

I am having trouble running custom node version on `node0.10` cartridge on open shift which you can find [here](https://github.com/DavidReinberger/openshift-meteor-leaderboard-customNode).

I get to install the new node version just great, however open shift keeps using the old node `10.25`.

Deoploy log:

```
remote: Activating deployment
remote:   - Checking to see if Node.js version 0.10.33 is installed ... 
remote:   - Node.js version 0.10.33 is already installed
remote: 
remote:   - pre_start_nodejs: Adding Node.js version 0.10.33 binaries to path
remote: -this is the path: /var/lib/openshift/54b6ea6e4382ece151000039/app-root/data/node-v0.10.33-linux-x64/bin:/var/lib/openshift/54b6ea6e4382ece151000039/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/.bin:/var/lib/openshift/54b6ea6e4382ece151000039//.node_modules/.bin:/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin 
remote:   - PATH set to include custom node version (0.10.33) from
remote:        /var/lib/openshift/54b6ea6e4382ece151000039/app-root/data/node-v0.10.33-linux-x64/bin 
remote:     PATH = /var/lib/openshift/54b6ea6e4382ece151000039/app-root/data/node-v0.10.33-linux-x64/bin:/var/lib/openshift/54b6ea6e4382ece151000039/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/.bin:/var/lib/openshift/54b6ea6e4382ece151000039//.node_modules/.bin:/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
remote: Starting NodeJS cartridge
```

Everything looks great and awesome, until I run the app which says: 10.25...

rhc tail:

```
v0.10.25

/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin:/opt/rh/v8314/root/usr/bin:/var/lib/openshift/54b6feb9e0b8cd56c00000e1/app-root/data/node-v0.10.33-linux-x64/bin:/var/lib/openshift/54b6feb9e0b8cd56c00000e1/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/.bin:/var/lib/openshift/54b6feb9e0b8cd56c00000e1//.node_modules/.bin:/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

undefined
```

Even when i `rhc ssh` to my app and try `node -v` i get 10.33...

on start time the PATH env gets overwritten and causes node to use the old bins...

PS: I am trying to deploy a Meteor app (1.0.2.1)

Comment: Have you tried these directions yet? https://blog.openshift.com/any-version-of-nodejs-you-want-in-the-cloud-openshift-does-it-paas-style/

Comment: Since the repo mentioned in the tutorial does not exist anymore I did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out :-)

If you want to use custom node @openshift take a look at [this repo](https://github.com/DavidReinberger/openshift-custom-nodejs).

Hope I get to help someone!